# Rails ActiveModel empty constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have an ActiveModel class Bar

This blows up

> Bar.new

My class looks like this:

```
require 'active_model'

class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations 
  include ActiveModel::Naming 

  def initialize(attributes={})
   #some code
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveModel::Name is a class not a module, it's not supposed to be included.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't actually have that in my code just typed the example wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Part of my learning experience.  I had another typo causing an issue, but I found it and it's working now.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jason Levens, could you please let us know what fixed your problem? Thanks